# ExtJS combo box data from json

Tags: json, extjs

i have json :

```
{"total":100, "category": [Village, City, School, HighSchool]}
```

for extjs combobox :

```
reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
root: 'category'},
[{name: 'category'}])
```

it not loods my data in it when i look in firebug it shows

thks for your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the error that firebug shows, but your JSON is invalid. Try:

```
{"total":100, "category": ["Village", "City", "School", "HighSchool"]}
//values in array should be in double quotes
```

Comment: ok i have changed the json style and populateing with not jsonstore only store